# ShowDialog() gets no DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is very odd.  I have never had this issue with ShowDialog in C#.  For some odd reason when the code developed for 64bit OS tries to show the Printer Dialog it never does it and the DialogResult is "None".  I have debugged it by stepping thru each line and see no clues.  I've checked the namespace and verified that I set proper references:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Here's the code:

```
    private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDoc.DefaultPageSettings = pgSettings;
        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        dlg.Document = printDoc;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }
```

The exact same code, in an almost identical version for 32 bit machines, has no problem.  The dialog is displayed, the user selects a printer, presses OK and the task is complete.

In the 64bit version, the ShowDialog() will not work for PrintDialog() but will work for PrintPreviewDialog()!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been answered elsewhere:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/a707d202-1a8b-43b1-9fff-08aa7ceb200a/

> Try setting  USEExDialog = True - It should work.

Comment: actually, the answer marked as correct on the page you linked to says to compile for 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you, that's true, I was misguided by the up votes.
@user1252604 I hope you noticed this and can let us know what worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I inserted dlg.UseEXDialog = true; before the dlg.ShowDialog() and it worked!!!  I really appreciate your help!!! - Bob T.

Comment: Graham, ericosg, I saw that one was suggesting that a solution is to

Comment: Graham, ericosg, I saw that one was suggesting that a solution is to set the cpu option to x86.  But this program is only used on 64 bit machines so I just added the UseEXDialog code and got the results I needed. (I waited longer than 5 minutes to finish this comment so I couldn't edit the comment right above).